# Accidental chown under / as root

Tags: data-recovery, chown

I accidentally run the following command as root
`chown mike -Rf / backups`
the point is that I added a space between / and backups my mistake, I stopped the command after 1-2 seconds, how can I recover from this? I have problems with DirectAdmin right now for example when accessing it I recive the error:

```
Unable to determine Usertype
user.conf needs to be repaired
http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=456
```

Or I stopped recieving emails, I dont even know what else is messed up right now...

Comment: Since it sounds like you have backups, I suggest comparing ownership info with the backups.

Comment: Note that the `chown` may also have cleared any setuid or setgid bits on the affected files, even if they were originally owned by root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to change this back without reverting to your backup as the system does not keep track of revision of ownership.

Best is to make a backup now, so any further changes can be rolled back.

Reinstalling the packages on your system probably resolves most of the ownership problems. On Debian/Ubuntu I would do:

```
apt-get install --reinstall package
```

on an `rpm` based system something like `rpm -Uvh --force package.rpm`
for anything that is giving trouble. If properly setup a package will not overwrite configuration files that you changed.

If you have another similar system, or a backup you can retrieve original ownership information from that an apply to your system. First make list of files and directories you are interested in using:

```
find / -user mike
```

and use that list to find not-mike-owned files in the backup or similar system.

Comment: I suggest you to **check [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68803/)** about package reinstallation under a Debian based system.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the OS you are running.

If it is Solaris 10 and older, you can fix all the owner issues affecting files and directories belonging to a package with the following command:

```
pkgchk -f
```

With Solaris 11, that would be:

```
pkg fix
```

I believe AIX has a similar package fix command.

If you run a rpm based OS (Red Hat, Fedora and the likes), you should be able to run

```
rpm -aV
```

to detect the files and directories with discrepancies against the package database. You might then fix them by running:

```
rpm --setugids <package-name>
```

But you would need to pass each affected package name. Alternatively, you might simply run:

```
for package in $(rpm -qa); do rpm --setugids $package; done
```

If you are running a debian based OS, I'm afraid file ownership isn't stored in the package database so you would need to either use your backup if any as a reference to restore the ownership, or find a similar system for the same.

Answer (score 2):

I did exactly the same mistake, by a typographic error at the end of the sentence

```
chown -R root:root /folder/subfolder /
```

I didn't realize the space before the slash  :(

Hopefully, asking here, finally I solved the problem, taking owner and group from another installed Debian server. In that server, I did:

```
find / -not -path '/proc/*' -not -path '/var/www/*' -not -path '/home/*' ! \(  -name root -o  -group root \) | xargs stat --format 'chown %U:%G %n' | sort -k 2,3 > chown_owner_and_group.sh
chmod +X chown_owner_and_group.sh
```

Then, I copy the file to the server where I need to restore the owner and group of files, and did an:

```
./chown_owner_and_group.sh
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for this answer. Totally saved my pc!

Comment: Sincerely, when I did it, I was afraid to reboot for first time that server ... but ALL WORKED!!! I had more to win than to loose  ;)   I am glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the only solution you have is to compare with another installation of the same distribution and reset the owners correctly.