# Locked myself out of Amazon EC2

Tags: ssh, permissions, amazon-ec2

I'm working with an Amazon EC2 instance and at some point, I wanted to `chown` a directory recursively, and it looks like I applied the command to the whole file system. As a result, it is possible that most files now have `ubuntu:www-data` ownership.

I didn't know how to revert that, and I realized this might be a problem only after I logged out of the instance. Now, when I try to `ssh` to my instance, I get the following error:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to www.myserver.com [Server IP address] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file AWS.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file AWS.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I don't have any other access to the server than SSH. Is there something I can do to access my server?

Note: this is not a duplicate of [Accidental chown under / as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74295) since my issue is not about reverting the `chown` but about logging back into the server.

Comment: You should start by sshing with the -v flag and display the results

Comment: @ryekayo Yep, I just added it in my question

Comment: Hmmm ok, this is a long shot but is there a way to SSH in as the user ubuntu?

Comment: @ryekayo This is what I always do (`ssh -i AWS.pem ubuntu@www.myserver.com`)

Comment: Would logging in with user `www-data` work?

Comment: Create another AWS vm, mount the original vm's disk under /mnt, and then choose to either fix permissions or migrate the data to the new vm.

Comment: @figgycity50 same result using `ubuntu`, `www-data` or `root`

Comment: @steve sounds like a good backup solution, thanks! at least I'm no longer freaking out about losing my data :)

Comment: @figgycity50, the www-data is the name of the group, not the user...

Comment: Your problem is, that your SSH configuration files, especially keyfiles don't belong to the "correct" user anymore. SSH is a bit allergic to that. If you're lucky, this http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15141/19575 can help you, if you can log in using a password, that is.